# Split line into multiple lines and append a substring in the beginning

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command-line

I'm very new to bash, and I have a log like this:

```
10, "a@gmail.com"
2, "b@gmail.com"
3333, "c@hotmail.com", "d@gmail.com"
4, "e@hotmail.com", "f@hotmail.com", "g@gmail.com"
55, "h@gmail.com"
```

I would like it to be:

```
10, "a@gmail.com"
2, "b@gmail.com"
3333, "c@hotmail.com"
3333, "d@gmail.com"
4, "e@hotmail.com" 
4, "f@hotmail.com" 
4, "g@gmail.com"
55, "h@gmail.com"
```

How do I do it in bash?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: edit your Q to show (what you think is) your best attempt to solve your problem. We're here to help you, but not to do it for you ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The standard UNIX tool for manipulating text is awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i}' file
10, "a@gmail.com"
2, "b@gmail.com"
3333, "c@hotmail.com"
3333, "d@gmail.com"
4, "e@hotmail.com"
4, "f@hotmail.com"
4, "g@gmail.com"
55, "h@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first argument, I'm passing the path to the file.
If no argument will be passed I will say about the error and will exit with (-1).

I'm iterating thru the file, with commas changed to space.
Each iteration I will be tacking separated by space word. If this word is the number I will store it and go to the next word. If it is non-numeric I will print the previous number and the current word, separated by the comma. Before the for loop, I'm initializing number with 0, just in case ;)

```
#!/bin/bash                             

if [ -z "${1}" ]; then                  
    echo "No file specified"            
    exit -1                                
else                                    
    file=$1                             
    echo "Parsing file \"$file\":"      
fi                                      

number="0"                              

for word in $(sed "s@,@ @g" $file); do   
    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]+ ]] ; then    
        number=${word};                 
        continue;                       
    else                                
        echo "$number, ${word}"         
    fi                                  
done                                    
exit 0
```

---

Run:

```
test@LAPTOP-EQKIVD8A:~$ cat new.txt
10, "a@gmail.com"
2, "b@gmail.com"
3333, "c@hotmail.com", "d@gmail.com"
4, "e@hotmail.com", "f@hotmail.com", "g@gmail.com"
55, "h@gmail.com"
test@LAPTOP-EQKIVD8A:~$ ./script.sh  new.txt
Parsing file "new.txt":
10, "a@gmail.com"
2, "b@gmail.com"
3333, "c@hotmail.com"
3333, "d@gmail.com"
4, "e@hotmail.com"
4, "f@hotmail.com"
4, "g@gmail.com"
55, "h@gmail.com"
```